# How to RoundUp a decimal value with a base distinct from degree of 10?

Tags: c#

A regular RoundUp function with a base of 10 looks as below:

```
public static decimal RoundUp(this decimal value, int decimals)
        {
            var k = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, decimals);
            return Math.Ceiling((value * k)) / k;
        }
```

so it works like this:

```
decimal number = 10.12345m;
number.RoundUp(3) => 10.124
number.RoundUp(2) => 10.13
number.RoundUp(1) => 10.2 
etc.
```

I would like to have a function that rounds up to the nearest value as the following:

```
decimal number = 10.12345m;
number.RoundUp(0.1) => 10.2          
number.RoundUp(0.25) => 10.25 
number.RoundUp(2.0) => 12
number.RoundUp(5.0) => 15 
number.RoundUp(10) => 20
```

Note RoundUp by @basis means the result is dividable on the @basis without the rest:

```
RoundUp(10.12345m, 0.15) => 10.2   check 10.2 / 0.15 = 68
```

neighbors are 10.05 and 10.35, so the correct rounding of 10.12345 is 10.2

```
RoundUp(5, 2.25) => 6.75   check 6.75 / 2.25 = 3
```

i.e. 2.25x2 =4.50 is less than 5. so 5 round up by 2.25 will be 6.75

```
RoundUp(5, 2.50) => 5.0   check 5 / 2.5 = 2
```

Comment: What should number.RoundUp(0.15m) and number.RoundUp(number) return? It seems another answerer took a different approach from what I took, so your question might be ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

You need to multiply the rounding factor by the ceiling of the division, as such:

```
public static decimal RoundUp(this decimal value, decimal round)
{
    return Math.Ceiling(value / round) * round;
}
```

Dotnetfiddle doesn't support extension methods, but here's a proof of concept: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BIkLC3

If you want to round to the next decimal, you need to round the whole and the decimal separately:

```
public static decimal RoundUp(decimal number, decimal round)
{
    decimal numberDecimal = number - Math.Truncate(number);
    decimal roundDecimal = round - Math.Truncate(round);
    decimal numberWhole = number - numberDecimal;
    decimal roundWhole = round - roundDecimal;
    if (roundWhole > 0)
        numberWhole = Math.Ceiling(number / roundWhole) * roundWhole;       
    if (roundDecimal > 0)
        roundDecimal = Math.Ceiling(numberDecimal / roundDecimal) * roundDecimal;
    return numberWhole + roundDecimal;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vqf0jB

Comment: Ah, in your code RoundUp(10.1m,10.1m) return 20.1m which I found odd, but OP never bothered to explain, for all we know it might be the correct answer in that case

Comment: it fails for cases RoundUp(5, 2.25) => 6.00    should be 6.75
RoundUp(5, 2.5) => 6.0       should be 5.0
RoundUp(5, 5.5) => 5.0       should be 5.5

Answer (score -1):

It turns out it's quite simple math:

```
 public static decimal RoundUp(this decimal value, decimal @base)
    {
        var n = Math.Ceiling((value + @base) / @base) -1;         
        return (n * @base);
    }   
}
```

[rextester link](https://rextester.com/LMTEBC72703)

Comment: Your solution fails a 0.15m rounding as well.

Comment: my solution RoundUp(10.12345, 0.15) => 10.20   which is 68 times by 0.15 so the line is 9.9, 10.05, 10.2. 10.35 etc.  10.12345 rounded up to the nearest 0.15 pips will be 10.2